# Grid properties on second child element of Accordion not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, grid, accordion

Here I have defined the parent element `display:"Grid"` and with my child element have defined the `gridColumnStart` as below. It's working fine with the first element but not with the second child element. Below have attached my code.

```
return (
  <Accordion
    sx={{
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 2fr 1fr"
    }}
  >
    <AccordionSummary
      sx={{
        gridColumnStart: "2",
        gridColumnEnd: "4"
      }}
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      aria-controls="panel1a-content"
      id="panel1a-header"
    >
      <div>
        <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ fontSize: "40px" }}>
          {props.Title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">{props.Description}</Typography>
        <Button
          size="small"
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            width: "140px",
            textAlign: "center",
            marginTop: "10px",
            color: "#2196F3",
            borderColor: "#2196F3"
          }}
        >
          More details
        </Button>
      </div>
    </AccordionSummary>

    <AccordionDetails
      sx={{
        gridColumnStart: "2",
        gridColumnEnd: "3"
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AccordionDetails>
  </Accordion>
);
```

So here gridColumnStart and End working with AccordionSummary but not with AccordionDetails.

[image]

This is how it looks but I wanted the text to be in the middle. Not sure if the approach I'm heading towards is correct. Would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified `Accordion` [definition](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Accordion/Accordion.js#L168-L186):

```
<AccordionRoot>
  <AccordionSummary />
  <TransitionComponent>
    <div>
      <AccordionDetail />
    </div>
  </TransitionComponent>
</AccordionRoot>
```

The reason your `AccordionDetail` styles doesn't work is because it's applied to the children of the grid item instead of the grid item itself. To fix it, you need to set the grid properties directly in the child of the grid container which is `TransitionComponent`, if you inspect the element you can see the class name of the DOM elelment is `MuiCollapse-root`:

```
<Accordion
  sx={{
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 2fr 1fr",
    "& .MuiCollapse-root": {
      gridColumnStart: "2",
      gridColumnEnd: "3"
    }
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]